# How to show youtube error screen with custom message in iframe using php

Tags: javascript, php, json, iframe, youtube

> I have an j son file which contains you tube video id's which i don't want to Play in iframe I want that when video is not present in json file will play and when it exists in json file it will not play and show an error screen with custom message that this video is restricted.like in youtube.
>
> when i use sandbox attribute then i could not get how to show custom message and this attribute is not working for firefox if any body has some solution then please help me. Here is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        $vid="0dV1Bwe2v6c";
        $str = file_get_contents('video.json');
        $json = json_decode($str, true);
        foreach ($json as  $value) {
           if($vid!=$value["id"]){
               $val="TRUE";
           }else{
               $val="FALSE";
           }
           }
             //echo $val;  
             if($val=="FALSE"){ ?>
        <div>
        <iframe width="700" height="345" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/<?php echo $vid; ?>?showinfo=0" sandbox> </iframe>
        </div>  
             <?php }else{
        ?>
        <div>
        <iframe width="700" height="345" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/<?php echo $vid; ?>?showinfo=0"> </iframe>
        </div>
             <?php } ?> 
    </body>
</html>
```

> here is the J SON file

```
[
{
"id": "0dV1Bwe2v6c"    
},
{
"id":"0dmhKtQ74wo"
},
{
"id":"0dV1Bwe2v6c"    
}
]
```

Comment: is your code working fine

Comment: no in firefox sandbox attribute is not working